# An examples of a linearly bounded set

Tags: vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Can someone clarify the following definition for me.

> Let $V$ be a real-valued vector space. A convex set $S$ in $V$ is
>   called linearly bounded when every straight line intersects $S$ in a 
>   bounded subset of that line.

Can someone please give me an example of such a set and a counter example. I have google around but can not find an example.

Comment: There is no logical statement, so we cannot strictly speak of a counterexample.  For an example, any bounded set is linearly bounded. The opposite is not true: the graph of y = x^2 is unbounded, but is linearly bounded.

Comment: @fund by a counterexample I meant a set that is not linearly bounded. Sorry.    Can we write this definition in terms of set notation? It would clarify things for me a lot.

Comment: Sure: $S$ is linearly bounded iff for any straight line $L$ exists an $M>0$ such that $S \cap L \subseteq B(0,M)$. A non example would be a line! Or the graph of $y = sin(x)$.

Comment: @funda Thank you. What if $V$ is a vector space of continuous function. What would be an example then? How do you define a line in such a case?

Comment: You can write any line as $L = \{x+ ty: t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ where $x,y$ are elements of your vector space.

Comment: @funda  But to defined bounded set I would need also a metric, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72135/discussion-between-funda-and-lisa).

Answer (score 0):

In $\ell^2$, define $C$ to be the convex hull of all sequences $(x_n)$ such that $(\forall n)$ $|x_n|\leq n$. This is clearly an unbounded set. However, it is linearly bounded. See https://www.univie.ac.at/EMIS/journals/HOA/AAA/Volume2003_2/620817.pdf and the references therein.